# How to update to iOS betas using iTunes

Tags: itunes, software-update, ios

I can update to iOS betas with OTA Updates, but a wired update from my computer through Finder/iTunes would provide faster download speeds.

Is there any way to do this without a developer account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The iPhone Wiki](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Beta_Firmware) has IPSW downloads for all beta releases, but some of the developer betas require a developer account.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could see it is not possible to download public beta's to iOS from your Mac. The only option Apple gives are OTA updates.

You could register as a developer, but the beta's are only available for paying developers.

If you are a developer, you can download beta's from [developer.apple.com/download](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

- Login
- Go to the iOS section
- Choose the right device
- Download
- Open iTunes
- Connect iOS device
- Click on the update button with alt (option) button pushed.
- Select the downloaded beta

Comment: Changed the URL. You need to login to access this page.

Comment: I am not a developer, I use the public beta.